# express.js and mysql authentication

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, forms, express

Hey guys I've been trying to create a signup form using `express.js` and `mysql` but my routes are not working as they are suppose to instead it is jumping to the else statement even with all the details filled in correctly, here is my code.

`User.js` content:

```
exports.register = function(req, res, next) {
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (req.body.name && req.body.email && req.body.password && req.body.confirmPassword) {

        // if user puts non matching passwords
        if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
            var err = new Error('passwords do not match ')
            err.status = 400;
            return next(err)
        } 
       // if user do not put name and email on registration
        if (!req.body.name && !req.body.email) {
            var err = new Error('Both name and email need to be inputed');
            err.status = 400;
            return next(err)
        }

       // if user puts correct info the get save to database
        var newUser = {
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword
        };

        connection.query('insert into Users set ?', newUser, function(err, results) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.flash("success", 'Welcome', newUser.name);
            req.session.user = newUser;
            res.redirect('/categories');
        });

    } else {
        var err = new Error('All fields must be filled. ')
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err)
    }
});
}
```

Can someone help me identify where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you show your `req.body` value?

Comment: its is returning a null value

Comment: Can you show you app.js file?

Answer (score 0):

Send your proper values from client side.

> And make sure to put your `body-parser` code above all the routes in your server main file.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: l already have that working, or do l need it it in the user.js file than the server.js file